# UnicodeDecodeError when using Python 2.x unicodecsv

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm trying to write out a csv file with Unicode characters, so I'm using the unicodecsv package. Unfortunately, I'm still getting UnicodeDecodeErrors:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import unicodecsv

raw_contents = 'He observes an “Oversized Gorilla” near Ashford'
encoded_contents = unicode(raw_contents, errors='replace')

with codecs.open('test.csv', 'w', 'UTF-8') as f:
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='UTF-8')
    w.writerow(["1", encoded_contents])
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicode_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    w.writerow(["1", encoded_contents])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/unicodecsv/__init__.py", line 83, in writerow
    self.writer.writerow(_stringify_list(row, self.encoding, self.encoding_errors))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I thought converting it to Unicode would be good enough, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'd really like to understand what is happening so that I'm better prepared to handle these errors in other projects in the future.

From the traceback, it looks like I can reproduce the error like this:

```
>>> raw_contents = 'He observes an “Oversized Gorilla” near Ashford'
>>> raw_contents.encode('UTF-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Up until now, I thought I had a decent working knowledge of working with Unicode text in Python 2.x, but this has humbled me.

Comment: FYI: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: `encoded_contents` is a misleading name. `unicode_text.encode(char_encoding) == bytes_data` and in reverse `bytes_data.decode(char_encoding) == unicode_text`. `encoded_contents` suggests (mistakenly) that it is a `bytes` object, not `unicode`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should *not* use `codecs.open()` for your file. `unicodecsv` wraps the `csv` module, which  always writes a *byte string* to the open file object. In order to write that byte string to a Unicode-aware file object such as returned by `codecs.open()`, it is implicitly *decoded*; this is where your `UnicodeDecodeError` exception stems from.

Use a file in binary mode instead:

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='UTF-8')
    w.writerow(["1", encoded_contents])
```

The binary mode is not strictly necessary unless your data contains embedded newlines, but the `csv` module wants to control how newlines are written to ensure that such values are handled correctly. However, not using `codecs.open()` is an absolute requirement.

The same thing happens when you call `.encode()` on a byte string; you *already* have encoded data there, so Python implicitly *decodes* to get a Unicode value to encode.

Comment: it is correct but it is not obvious that a file object (for a drop-in csv module replacement that supports Unicode) should be binary. It requires a binary file because `unicodecsv` is a *thin* wrapper around `csv` module that works only with binary data on Python 2. Otherwise csv format can be defined for a text stream too (like JSON).

Comment: However, not using codecs.open() is an absolute requirement == `u'unicode sample'.encode('utf-8')` == `UnicodeDecodeError`??

Comment: @SIslam: if *all of your data* is ASCII safe (it'll be *decoded as ASCII*, not `UTF-8`), then you can get away with using `codecs.open()`. However, that's pretty useless; you could just have used a regular file and not Python do a useless decode-encode dance.